# Search for an exact match in string

Tags: matlab

Given a table with the following format in MATLAB:

```
  itemids        keywords
    1            3D,children,anim,pixar,3D,3D pixar 
    2            3D,4D pixar,3D car
    ...            ...
```

I want to count the number of times each keyword is repeated in each item. All the list of **unique** keywords are available in `keywords = {'3D';'Children';'anim';'pixar' ...}`. The output is a matrix `TF` with rows equal to the number of items and columns equal to `length(keywords)`.

One of the difficulties here is to search for an exact match for each string. I am currently using `strcmp()` which seems to be giving all the entries with a given word, not exact match. In my case I would need to differentiate between `3D` and `3D pixar`.

Comment: At least give us the code that creates your table, so we can perform some tests. However, your task can easily by solved with a combination of `strcmp()` and `cellfun()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `ismember` function in MATLAB. I am assuming that keywords for each item is actually a single string in which case you will need to split the keywords before doing `ismember`.

```
relevantKeyWords = {'3D','Children','anim','pixar'};
keywordsInItem = strtrim(strsplit(keywordsStr,',')) % Split the words and trim each word

tmp = ismember(relevantKeywords,keywordsInItem);
```

tmp will be of size 1 x length(relevantKeywords) indicating if the relevant keyword was found.